# Randomly select an element from an enumeration in a type-safe way with newest C++

Tags: c++, enums, type-safety

Is there a way to randomly select an element from an enumeration in a type-safe way?

The best way to do it, that I could find, is to introduce a terminator value as the last element of the enum, so you know how many values there are, then generate a random integer in the appropriate range that you cast to the enum.  But a terminator value does not represent anything, so then you have an invalid enum value, and this is not type-safe.  Is there a better way to do it in the latest C++ standards?

Comment: Interesting question, but it all boils down to "is there a universal, type-safe way of determining how many values are in an enum?", and the answer to that is, sadly, no. The standard idiom is, as you mention, to include a sentinel value in the enum, but I agree that is ugly. Your only other solution really would be to write a custom class to represent your enum, providing some kind of implicit conversion, but that is almost certainly over-engineered. Besides, it gets worse than it first seems: the values in an enum don't have to be linearly increasing; there can be jumps and discontinuities.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a good use case for a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```cpp
std::map<std::string, const int> nicer_enum {{"Do", 3}, {"Re", 6}, {"Mi", 9}};

std::cout << nicer_enum["Re"] << '\n'; // 6

auto elem = nicer_enum.cbegin();
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
std::advance(elem, std::rand() % nicer_enum.size());
std::cout << elem->second << '\n'; // 3, 6 or 9

for (const auto &kv : nicer_enum)
        std::cout << kv.first << ": " << kv.second << ' '; // Do: 3 Mi: 9 Re: 6

std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Nice! But it would be better if you used `<random>` and `std::string` instead of pre-C++11 techniques.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't want to distract from the relevant part of my answer. (And you probably shouldn't be resizing map keys anyhow).

Comment: @RayHamel: The use of `const char *` *does* distract from the relevant part of your answer.

Comment: @RayHamel: It is also wrong if you expect there to be any order among the keys. In particular, there is no lexicographical order, i.e. it's not guaranteed to be "Do", "Mi", "Re" (nor "Do", "Re", "Mi", or any other order).

Comment: Fair enough, again, ordering isn't relevant to this specific question, but you're right that one should use a type with a known ordering.

Comment: @Oktalist: no it is not UB. std::less allows comparison of unrelated pointers.

Comment: @Oktalist: It would be a pretty severe defect in the C++ standard if you could not use pointers as map keys or set elements. Fortunately, `std::less` is defined to work with pointers. So there is no UB.